# Is it correct to say (They elected him as a chairman)?

Tags: articles

An explanation in my grammar book tells me that some expressions have no article:

> 1. He was **elected President**.
> 2. She **became Queen**.
> 3. They **made** her **Manager**.

According to Cambridge Dictionary, chairman is countable and in relation with the title, is it correct to say:

> They didn't elect him **as a** Chairman.

The sentence above is taken from my book. I don't know why they wrote **C** in capital. Anyway, this is the original sentence:

> They didn't elect him Chairman - he gave himself the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either is correct:
elect him as chairman
elect him chairman

The word may be capitalized *Chairman* because it is the proper name of a position in a particular context.

*elect him as a chairman *
is also possible, but that makes the capitalization less likely to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

"Elect him as a chairman" sounds fine to me grammatically, though in this case it should probably be "the", since there's only one chairman. ("A chairman" would be fine in a case where chairmen of multiple committees are being elected.)